# PHP foreach armar una tabla

Tags: array, post

Tengo una página donde recibo arrays por el método _POST desde un formulario y necesito crear una fila con cada grupo de datos:

```
$idfila = $_POST['idfila'];
$destino = $_POST['destino'];
$pedidohs = $_POST['pedidohs'];
$pedido_desarrollo = $_POST['pedido_desarrollo'];
$rendicionhs = $_POST['rendicionhs'];

if (isset($idfila))
{
foreach ($idfila as $clave=>$idfilarecibido)
{
echo '<tr>';
foreach ($destino as $clave=>$destinorecibido)
{
echo '<td>'.$destinorecibido.'</td>';
}
foreach ($pedidohs as $clave=>$pedidohsrecibido)
{
echo '<td>'.$pedidohsrecibido.'</td>';
}
foreach ($pedido_desarrollo as $clave=>$pedido_desarrollorecibido)
{
echo '<td>'.$pedido_desarrollorecibido.'</td>';
}
foreach ($rendicionhs as $clave=>$rendicionhsrecibido)
{
echo '<td>'.$rendicionhsrecibido.'</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
}
}
```

No logro armar una tabla con cada grupo de datos, fila por fila.

Los arrays que recibo son variables y los resultados similares a lo siguiente:

array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" } 
array(3) { [1]=> string(12) "Belgrano 361" [2]=> string(9) "Salta 244" [3]=> string(11) "Bulnes 1544" } 
array(3) { [1]=> string(5) "14:00" [2]=> string(5) "14:30" [3]=> string(5) "17:00" } 
array(3) { [1]=> string(5) "Sobre" [2]=> string(4) "Pago" [3]=> string(8) "Cobranza" } 
array(3) { [1]=> string(5) "16:00" [2]=> string(5) "17:00" [3]=> string(5) "18:00" }

Y necesito mostrarlo del siguiente modo:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Destino</th>
<th>Hora de Gesti&oacute;n</th>
<th>Desarrollo del tr&aacute;mite</th>
<th>Hora de Rendici&oacute;n</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Belgrano 361</td>
<td>14:00</td>
<td>Sobre</td>
<td>16:00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>Salta 244</td>
<td>14:30</td>
<td>Pago</td>
<td>17:00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>Bulnes 1544</td>
<td>17:00</td>
<td>Cobranza</td>
<td>18:00</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Alguna sugerencia?
Muchas gracias!

Comment: estás teniendo en cuenta poner `<table>`?

Comment: Si, si. Lo tengo en cuenta,y está esa etiqueta, pero lo que me sucede es que los datos me los muestra mal. Un dato al lado del otro, sin hacer un salto de fila por cada grupo de datos.

Comment: lo que sucede es que como tienes varios arreglos al ingresar a un foreach te va a mostrar lo que contiene cada arreglo antes de seguir, agrupar todo en un solo arreglo podría ser una solución. Los `arreglos` tienen la misma **longitud**?

Comment: Los arreglos son valores diferentes y variables, que tipean los usuarios en un formulario. No siempre son la misma cantidad de filas, porque se agregan filas mediante Javascript.
No sé cómo hacer para agrupar todo en un solo arreglo y luego desarrollarlo fila por fila. Es lo que no logro.

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/101412/edit)  colocando un ejemplo de cómo son las arreglos. Sería muy útil de cara a una respuesta. También, intenta aclarar lo que quieres decir cuando afirmas esto: _necesito crear una tabla con cada grupo de datos_ Si es que recibes varios arrays y quieres crear una tabla con cada uno, o bien crear una sola tabla con todos los arrays juntos, etc. Esa parte no queda nada clara en la pregunta.

Comment: Ademas de lo que pide A.Cedano, agrega los resultados de tu código actual, Es bastante útil para saber que está mal con ello.

Comment: Ya agregué detalles de los arrays y cómo necesito mostrarlo. Espero que esté más claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que he entendido, recibes en arrays separados los valores de las columnas, no de las filas.

primero deberias verificar que todos los arrays tienen el mismo numero de elementos, sino lo siguiente que te expongo puede no funcionarte.

```
$idfila = $_POST['idfila'];
$destino = $_POST['destino'];
$pedidohs = $_POST['pedidohs'];
$pedido_desarrollo = $_POST['pedido_desarrollo'];
$rendicionhs = $_POST['rendicionhs'];

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>id</th><th>destino</th><th>pedidohs</th><th>pedido_desarrollo</th><th>rendicionhs</th></tr>";
foreach($idfila as $fila) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $fila . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $destino[$fila] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $pedidohs[$fila] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $pedido_desarrollo[$fila] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $rendicionhs[$fila] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>">
}

echo "</table>";
```

Esto esta basado en los resultados de arrays que has puesto en tu definicion. Por ello, he cogido el primer array (los idFila) que indican un numero y es el que uso como indice en los demas, ya que precisamente sus indices son esos numeros.

Comment: Excelente! Es esto!
Muchas gracias!